# How could two equal numbers not be equal in PHP

Tags: php

I have two numbers which are supposed to be equal to return a difference, I doesn't make sense...

The only way to be able to reproduce this problem here I had to base64_encode my arrays,

here is the script:

basically the script will fix numbers like "1 234,5" to "1234.5" and does calculations, but at the ends it  returns

```
            First Number: 4784.47
            Second Number: 4784.47
            Difference: 9.0949470177293E-13
```

I just don't understand????????

---

```
            $aa = 'YTo3OntpOjA7YToxMDp7czoxMToiRGVzY3JpcHRpb24iO3M6MTI6IkvDqWsgc3rDoW1vayI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA4LjEwLTA4LjEwLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MToiMSI7czoxMjoiRHVyYXRpb25UaW1lIjtzOjc6IjA6MDQ6MDAiO3M6MTI6Ik5ldFVuaXRQcmljZSI7czo1OiIzNSwyMCI7czo5OiJOZXRBbW91bnQiO3M6NjoiMTQwLDgwIjtzOjEwOiJWQVRQZXJjZW50IjtzOjM6IjI1JSI7czozOiJWQVQiO3M6NToiMzUsMjAiO3M6MTE6Ikdyb3NzQW1vdW50IjtzOjY6IjE3NiwwMCI7czo4OiJJdGVtQ29kZSI7czo0OiJCTFVFIjt9aToxO2E6MTA6e3M6MTE6IkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjtzOjE3OiJCZWxmw7ZsZGkgaMOtdsOhcyI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA3LjIyLTA4LjExLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MjoiMTIiO3M6MTI6IkR1cmF0aW9uVGltZSI7czo3OiIwOjIxOjQzIjtzOjEyOiJOZXRVbml0UHJpY2UiO3M6NToiMTUsMjAiO3M6OToiTmV0QW1vdW50IjtzOjY6IjMzMCwxMCI7czoxMDoiVkFUUGVyY2VudCI7czozOiIyNSUiO3M6MzoiVkFUIjtzOjU6IjgyLDUyIjtzOjExOiJHcm9zc0Ftb3VudCI7czo2OiI0MTIsNjIiO3M6ODoiSXRlbUNvZGUiO3M6ODoiRklYX0ZMQVQiO31pOjI7YToxMDp7czoxMToiRGVzY3JpcHRpb24iO3M6MjM6IkVnecOpYiBtb2JpbCBlZ3lzw6lnw6FyIjtzOjY6IlBlcmlvZCI7czoxMjoiMDcuMjEtMDguMTEuIjtzOjY6IkFtb3VudCI7czoyOiI1MCI7czoxMjoiRHVyYXRpb25UaW1lIjtzOjc6IjE6MDE6MzgiO3M6MTI6Ik5ldFVuaXRQcmljZSI7czo1OiIxNSwyMCI7czo5OiJOZXRBbW91bnQiO3M6NjoiOTM2LDgzIjtzOjEwOiJWQVRQZXJjZW50IjtzOjM6IjI1JSI7czozOiJWQVQiO3M6NjoiMjM0LDIxIjtzOjExOiJHcm9zc0Ftb3VudCI7czo4OiIxIDE3MSwwNCI7czo4OiJJdGVtQ29kZSI7czo4OiJPRkZfRkxBVCI7fWk6MzthOjEwOntzOjExOiJEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI7czoxOToiVm9kYWZvbmUgZWd5c8OpZ8OhciI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA3LjE1LTA4LjEyLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MjoiMjAiO3M6MTI6IkR1cmF0aW9uVGltZSI7czo3OiIwOjU0OjM3IjtzOjEyOiJOZXRVbml0UHJpY2UiO3M6NToiMTUsMjAiO3M6OToiTmV0QW1vdW50IjtzOjY6Ijc2MywwNSI7czoxMDoiVkFUUGVyY2VudCI7czozOiIyNSUiO3M6MzoiVkFUIjtzOjY6IjE5MCw3NiI7czoxMToiR3Jvc3NBbW91bnQiO3M6NjoiOTUzLDgxIjtzOjg6Ikl0ZW1Db2RlIjtzOjc6Ik9OX0ZMQVQiO31pOjQ7YToxMDp7czoxMToiRGVzY3JpcHRpb24iO3M6MTU6Ik5lbXpldGvDtnppIFNNUyI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA3LjEzLTA4LjEzLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MjoiNDIiO3M6MTI6IkR1cmF0aW9uVGltZSI7czoxOiItIjtzOjEyOiJOZXRVbml0UHJpY2UiO3M6NToiMzAsNDAiO3M6OToiTmV0QW1vdW50IjtzOjg6IjEgMjc2LDgwIjtzOjEwOiJWQVRQZXJjZW50IjtzOjM6IjI1JSI7czozOiJWQVQiO3M6NjoiMzE5LDIwIjtzOjExOiJHcm9zc0Ftb3VudCI7czo4OiIxIDU5NiwwMCI7czo4OiJJdGVtQ29kZSI7czo3OiJTTVNfSU5UIjt9aTo1O2E6MTA6e3M6MTE6IkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjtzOjIzOiJTTVMgaMOhbMOzemF0b24ga8OtdsO8bCI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA3LjI1LTA4LjExLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MjoiMTUiO3M6MTI6IkR1cmF0aW9uVGltZSI7czoxOiItIjtzOjEyOiJOZXRVbml0UHJpY2UiO3M6NToiMTUsMjAiO3M6OToiTmV0QW1vdW50IjtzOjY6IjIyOCwwMCI7czoxMDoiVkFUUGVyY2VudCI7czozOiIyNSUiO3M6MzoiVkFUIjtzOjU6IjU3LDAwIjtzOjExOiJHcm9zc0Ftb3VudCI7czo2OiIyODUsMDAiO3M6ODoiSXRlbUNvZGUiO3M6NzoiU01TX09GRiI7fWk6NjthOjEwOntzOjExOiJEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI7czoyMjoiU01TIGjDoWzDs3phdG9uIGJlbMO8bCI7czo2OiJQZXJpb2QiO3M6MTI6IjA3LjE3LTA4LjEyLiI7czo2OiJBbW91bnQiO3M6MjoiMTUiO3M6MTI6IkR1cmF0aW9uVGltZSI7czoxOiItIjtzOjEyOiJOZXRVbml0UHJpY2UiO3M6NToiMTUsMjAiO3M6OToiTmV0QW1vdW50IjtzOjY6IjE1MiwwMCI7czoxMDoiVkFUUGVyY2VudCI7czozOiIyNSUiO3M6MzoiVkFUIjtzOjU6IjM4LDAwIjtzOjExOiJHcm9zc0Ftb3VudCI7czo2OiIxOTAsMDAiO3M6ODoiSXRlbUNvZGUiO3M6NjoiU01TX09OIjt9fQ==';
```

---

```
            $tt = 'YTozOntzOjE2OiJTdW1tYXJ5SXRlbU5ldHRvIjtzOjg6IjMgODI3LDU4IjtzOjE0OiJTdW1tYXJ5SXRlbVZBVCI7czo2OiI5NTYsODkiO3M6MTc6IlN1bW1hcnlJdGVtQnJ1dHRvIjtzOjg6IjQgNzg0LDQ3Ijt9';
```

---

```
            $a = unserialize(base64_decode($aa));
            $t = unserialize(base64_decode($tt));


            function calculate_call_fees($a,$t){

                $or_item = 0;

                foreach($a as $k => $r) {
                    $or_item += fix_num($r['GrossAmount']); 
                }        

                $br =  fix_num($t['SummaryItemBrutto']);   

                if($br>$or_item){
                    $diff = $br-$or_item;
                } else {
                    $diff = 0;
                }

                echo 'First Number: ' . $br.'<br/>';
                echo 'Second Number: ' . $or_item.'<br />';
                echo 'Difference: ' . $diff.'<br />';

                echo '<hr />';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($a);
                echo '</pre>';
                echo '<hr />';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($t);
                echo '</pre>';    

            }

            function fix_num($n){
                return floatval(str_replace(Array(" ",","),array("","."),$n));
            }

            calculate_call_fees($a,$t);
```

Comment: 9.0949470177293E-13 is a **VERY** small difference. Have you tried using === to compare the 2 numbers?

Comment: the magic of floating point math: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Floating point calculations are inexact (lossy). Just because they print out alike does not mean they are actually identical in their binary representation (which is what `==` however tests for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "equals" comparison with floating point numbers is dangerous because of floating point limited precision - you're liable to get small differences due to the rounding involved.

Instead, if you want to see if two floating point numbers are "the same", just see if their difference is below a certain threshold:

```
if( abs($a - $b) < 0.00000001) {
    // a and b are "equal"
}
```

Comment: hmm. thank you, didnt know about that.  though if I used "if($br>fix_num($or_item))", it returns zero too, though "fix_num" does nothing special????  
does this mean every calculation I make with floats will suffer from small differences?

Comment: If you use this, make sure you use the abs() function, in case $b value is greater than $a, like so: if(abs($a-$b) < .0000001) {... Of course assumes both values are of the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just PHP. There is a general problem of representing fractional numbers in the computer. It's subject for various types of overflows, underflows, precision issues and so on. [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) shed some light on the topic.

The general rule - if you demand for two 'seem-equal' numbers to be guaranteed equal - don't use floating point data types (float, double), but fixed point (decimal, numeric)

Comment: so I should convert my floats to decimal?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as this is "Machine epsilon" issue:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Try to compare the difference between them with 0.000001 instead of comparing them directly.